# Do less severe log level INCLUDE more severe log levels?

Tags: linux-kernel, u-boot, kernel-parameters

Will `loglevel=7` include the logs, for example, that would be produced by `loglevel=0`?

http://www.makelinux.net/ldd3/chp-4-sect-2

Answer (score 0, accepted):

loglevel=7 will include loglevels 0-6.

**Source**: From the link you posted: "The new level is specified as an integer value between 1 and 8, inclusive. If it is set to 1, only messages of level 0 (KERN_EMERG) reach the console; if it is set to 8, all messages, including debugging ones, are displayed."